# Inno Setup Search for specifc file on a CD, retrieve exact filepath and return value to [Files]-Section

Tags: inno-setup

I want to make an installer for an old program which comes on 2 CDs and I want to install the files directly from the discs.

At start up the setup should check if a certain file exists which means the first CD is inserted into the cd rom drive.
This is the code for that task:

```
[Files]
Source: {code: ??? }; Destination: {app}; flags:external;

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  if not FileExists('A:\Resource\CD1.GOB') xor
         FileExists('B:\Resource\CD1.GOB') xor
         // and so on, for every drive letter...
         FileExists('Z:\Resource\CD1.GOB') then
         Repeat
           if MsgBox('Insert the first CD!', mbInformation, MB_OKCANCEL) = IDCANCEL then
           ExitProcess(0);
         Until  FileExists('A:\Resource\CD1.GOB') or
                FileExists('B:\Resource\CD1.GOB') or
                // going through all letters again...
                FileExists('Z:\Resource\CD1.GOB') = true;
```

So this works as intended. If the CD is not inserted and thus the file cannot be found a message will be shown which asks the user to insert the CD.

But I am wondering if there is a better way to increment the drive letter, because this is quite a mess.

And second, how can I save the full filepath und pass it on to the [Files] section?

I hope you can help me with this!

UPDATE:

I tried it again and came up with this:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageId = wpWelcome then
  begin
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := False; 
    repeat
      for i:=0 to 31 do
        dstr := (Chr(Ord('A') + i) + ':\Resource\CD1.gob');
    until FileExists(dstr);
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := True; 
  end;
end;
```

But using this code Setup freezes at the beginning and doesn't respond even if the CD is already inserted.

Comment: Well, I want to go for a different approach now. When using my method the wizard will wait if you insert a CD and click OK in the message box until it has checked the CD. That's because Setup checks twice. So I want to get rid of the message box and implement this check (probably yours) on the welcome page. There will be a message displayed which says "Insert the CD" until the specific file has been found on a CD-ROM drive. And the Next button should be greyed out until the file has been found.

Comment: Ok, seems my post doesn't fit you, so post your own answer and accept it... Now I regret I've been wasting my time to prepare the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I can still use it a little differently. And maybe your answer can help someone else, so go and post it! I am not sure whether I can do it like I imagne it to work.

Comment: Well, maybe we didn't understand each other. You've been asking how to optimize your script to not write each drive letter to find a certain file on a CD. Well, you might use some loop, where you'd increment letter from `A` to `Z` and build the path from this, but who can guarantee, that your user won't have that file for instance on drive `D`, which can be a hard drive ? I've used a different approach in [my script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12379740/960757). I get the list just of all CD/DVD drives, and check for that file existence only on them (what makes this check little bit safer).

Comment: I took a look at it again. It doesn't matter if the file is on a CD or hard disk. And I wanted to implement the check on the welcome page so the Next button is disabled until the file is found. But I implemented it incorrectly thus the wizard didn't respond anymore.

Comment: Please consider my updated first post!

Comment: If I overlook, that you've originally asked how to search for a specific file on CD (what I've answered and would be fair if you'd accept it), the solution you've provided in your update may block the responsibility of the wizard form. You need to let the messages to be processed, but that's what you can't actually do in InnoSetup now. Windows may take it as unresponsible program and offer your user to terminate it due to this block.

Comment: So... What do I have to improve?

Comment: If you run such setup, you're in fact in (almost) infinite loop, which doesn't allow Windows message queue to be processed (and this is needed for the whole user interaction, like window moving, clicking; just everything how user can interact with the setup). To prevent this, you need to tell the application to process this queue, what is done (in Delphi) by the [`ProcessMessages`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessages) method. Unfortunately, this method is not published in InnoSetup at this time, so there's no way to fix that.

Comment: There is the [`InnoSetup with extended Delphi language support`](http://restools.hanzify.org/article.asp?id=89), which has the `Application` object with its `ProcessMessages` published. Using it inside of your loop will give the users back the responsibility of your setup.

Comment: Yes, I showed this to you :D So when do I have to call ProcessMessages in my script? And do I have to alter it in any way?

Comment: Ah, I forgot :-) Put it inside the `repeat` loop e.g. right after the `for` loop (like [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/ji3jh72N)). Except that loop block (which you'll resolve by that `ProcessMessages` call), the code is fine.

Comment: I got a workaround: http://pastebin.com/WH9qFUEt   I just cannot confirm the abortion of the setup. I can click abort but clicking yes doesn't work. Otherwise everything works great. The repeat-until loop didn't work at all, that's why I did this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do what you need:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: {code:GetFileSource}; DestDir: {app}; flags:external;

[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif
type
  TDriveType = (
    dtUnknown,
    dtNoRootDir,
    dtRemovable,
    dtFixed,
    dtRemote,
    dtCDROM,
    dtRAMDisk
  );
  TDriveTypes = set of TDriveType;
function GetDriveType(lpRootPathName: string): UINT;
  external 'GetDriveType{#AW}@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function GetLogicalDriveStrings(nBufferLength: DWORD; lpBuffer: string): DWORD;
  external 'GetLogicalDriveStrings{#AW}@kernel32.dll stdcall';

var
  FileSource: string;

#ifndef UNICODE
function IntToDriveType(Value: UINT): TDriveType;
begin
  Result := dtUnknown;
  case Value of
    1: Result := dtNoRootDir;
    2: Result := dtRemovable;
    3: Result := dtFixed;
    4: Result := dtRemote;
    5: Result := dtCDROM;
    6: Result := dtRAMDisk;
  end;
end;
#endif

function GetLogicalDrives(var ADrives: array of string; 
  AFilter: TDriveTypes): Integer;
var
  S: string;
  I: Integer;
  DriveRoot: string;
begin
  Result := 0;
  SetArrayLength(ADrives, 0);

  I := GetLogicalDriveStrings(0, #0);
  if I > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(S, I);
    if GetLogicalDriveStrings(Length(S), S) > 0 then
    begin
      S := TrimRight(S);
      I := Pos(#0, S);
      while I > 0 do
      begin
        DriveRoot := Copy(S, 1, I - 1);
        #ifdef UNICODE
        if (AFilter = []) or
          (TDriveType(GetDriveType(DriveRoot)) in AFilter) then
        #else
        if (AFilter = []) or
          (IntToDriveType(GetDriveType(DriveRoot)) in AFilter) then
        #endif
        begin
          SetArrayLength(ADrives, GetArrayLength(ADrives) + 1);
          #ifdef UNICODE
          ADrives[High(ADrives)] := DriveRoot;
          #else
          ADrives[GetArrayLength(ADrives) - 1] := DriveRoot;
          #endif
        end;
        Delete(S, 1, I);
        I := Pos(#0, S);
      end;
      Result := GetArrayLength(ADrives);
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetFileSource(Value: string): string;
begin
  // file source path passed to the [Files] section
  Result := FileSource;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  I: Integer;
  DriveCount: Integer;
  DriveArray: array of string;
begin
  // the function will fill the DriveArray only with CDROM
  // drives and returns the count of found drives
  DriveCount := GetLogicalDrives(DriveArray, [dtCDROM]);
  // here you have an array of CD-ROM drives so iterate it
  // search for a file you need and when you find it, pass
  // the path to the FileSource variable, which will later
  // be queried to get the source to the file in [Files]
  for I := 0 to DriveCount - 1 do
  begin
    if FileExists(DriveArray[I] + 'Resource\CD1.GOB') then
    begin
      FileSource := DriveArray[I] + 'Resource\CD1.GOB';
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  MsgBox('File was found on path: ' + FileSource, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```