# Inno Setup install script from CD/DVD drive (variable path)

Tags: path, inno-setup, cddvd

I am trying to write a Inno Setup script to install files from a CD drive to a predefined system C drive folder. Naturally, the CD/DVD ROM may have a different path ID on different systems. How do I code this variable path for the Source Files?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your installer is located along with the files you are going to install, you can use the [`{src}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=src) to refer to installer's folder along with the [`external` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=external):

```
[Files]
Source: "{src}\file.dat"; DestDir: "..."; Flags: external
```

---

If your installer is located elsewhere, there's no generic solution. Note that there may be even more CD/DVD drives on the computer.

You would have to programmatically enumerate all drives, testing for their type (CD/DVD) and presence of certain files for example.

Comment: You can at least [`narrow the drive`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12379740/960757) in which a file unique to the setup package is.

Comment: I tried  that but the compiler gives me an error:

No files found matching
"C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\{src}file.dat"

I am running the compiler from my desktop, and the source files are on a different drive (F Drive).

Comment: OK, You have to add `Flags: external` so that the compiler does not try to locate files on compile-time (when constant resolution does not work in `Source` attribute). See my updated answer.